# ¿Cómo puedo indexar una columna con el tipo de dato varbinay en SQL Server?

Tags: indices, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo una tabla con varios campos, uno de esos campos es de tipo de dato *varbinary(max) filestream*, es decir almacena contenedores de archivos.

Quiero saber si posible de alguna forma indexar ese campo, ya que intente de la forma clásica:

```
create index 'mi_index' non clustered..........
```

Pero no se puede me dice que es invalido para ese campo. Mi tabla tiene como columna un identificador *rowguidcol unique* necesario para la columna de archivo, y esa columna si tiene un índice único. Aparte mi tabla tiene el índice agrupado del ID y algunos otros índices mas no agrupados. Esta tabla tiene cerca de tres millones de registros y puede crecer con el tiempo. El campo archivo permite valores nulos. La necesidad surge porque hay aplicativos que van a buscar por ese campo archivo. Incluso cuando en el SQL Server para probar hago la siguiente consulta:

```
select 1 from 'Mi tabla' where ID=30 and 'campo_archivo' is null
```

Debería de retornar el valor 1 sin problemas y en tan solo unos segundos, como lo hace cuando hago la misma consulta pero solo con el id de filtro. El valor de archivo para ese campo especifico es *null* así que debería ejecutarse sin problemas, pero se queda cargando y no muestra nada. Solo he esperado como 10m porque debería de cargar en segundos y luego he anulado la ejecución, no se si llegara a cargar en más tiempo. Por lo que yo creo que no esta leyendo el campo archivo de forma correcta o tiene problemas para encontrarlo, pienso que quizás indexando ese campo me pueda ayudar. Alguna recomendación o sugerencia.

El error que me sale cuando intento crear el índice es:

> Column 'Archivo' in table 'My_table' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in a index o statistics

Comment: Jum, hasta donde recuerdo, el tipo de dato varbinary se añadió en 2008 y no recuerdo cómo se comporta. Por favor, actualiza la pregunta con el mensaje completo de error

Comment: @Alfabravo le añadí el mensaje de error que el Sql Server me retorna cuando intento crear el índice para ese campo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes indexar el campo `varbinary`, el motor lo permite si no excede de cierto tamaño, no lo va a permitir con `varbinary(max)`. Otra cosa es que sea eficiente en espacio ocupado por el índice y el resultado en la velocidad de resolución de la consulta. Dependerá del tamaño de la tabla.

Con `varbinary(max)`

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Nombre_indice   
    ON Tabla (CampoVarbinary);
```

El resultado es de error:

> La columna 'XXXXXX' de la tabla 'dbo.XXXXX' es de un tipo que no es
> válido para usarse como columna de clave en un índice.

Si el campo es menor: varbinary(5000) lanza una advertencia:

> La máxima longitud de clave para un índice no agrupado es de 1700
> bytes. El índice XXXXXXX tiene una longitud máxima de 5000 bytes. Para
> algunas combinaciones de valores grandes, la operación de inserción o
> actualización no funcionará correctamente.

Personalmente yo me inclinaría por añadir un campo a la tabla que fuera `bit` que indicara si el campo `varbinary` tiene datos o no. Eso lo puedes gestionar fácilmente mediante un `trigger`.

Comment: No me deja crear el índice para ese campo, el sqlserver me dice que esa columna es de un tipo que es inválido para usar como una columna clave en un índice.

Comment: En la [documentación de esta versión](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190197(v=sql.105)) 2008 R2 indica que si es posible aunque no pueden ser una columna de clave de índice.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, quiere decir que no puede ser la columna clave para el índice, es decir si podría incluirlo como columna secundaria en un índice. Si a eso se refiere, pues ya lo intente también y tampoco me deja.

Comment: Tienes razón, la documentación no es clara. He realizado unas pruebas, he puesto el resultado en la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora que lo mencionas recuerdo haber leído en alguna documentación que si se puede añadir un índice para ese tipo de dato varbinary siempre y cuando no sea (max). y eso tiene lógica con tus pruebas. En mi caso es varbinary(max) entonces si o si debe ser de otra manera, no de la forma convencional o quizás el sql server no lo permita en si.

Comment: Esta respuesta puede ayudar, tiene una opción interesante https://stackoverflow.com/a/2864174/236345 \\ @Abel SQLServer NO lo va a permitir, fin. Tienes que cambiar la forma en la que defines el campo y/o el índice.